# Is it ok to have section tag within footer tag in HTML5?

Tags: html

I'm new to HTML5 markup.

I'm wondering if I'm allowed to have a section tag within footer like the below.

```
<article>
    <header class="content__header">
    </header>

    <section class="content__body">
    </section>

    <footer class="content__footer>
        <section class="relatedArticles">
        </section>
        <section class="pagination">
        </section>
    </footer>

</article>
```

The w3c document doesn't explain much about footer tag usage.

Thanks!!

Comment: Simply, yes. Completely valid HTML5.

Comment: As per [rfc](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-section-element) section is valid Where [flow content](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#flow-content-1) is expected. So it is completely valid.

Comment: "The w3c document doesn't explain much about footer tag usage." Are you sure? I see plenty of examples [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-footer-element).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> The w3c document doesn't explain much about footer tag usage.

...actually, it does. Section 4.3.8 `<footer>` ( http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-footer-element ) states:

> Content model: [Flow content](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#flow-content-1), but with no header, footer, or main element descendants.

[The section of the specifiction defining "Flow content" (3.2.4.1.2) lists all "flow" elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#flow-content-1), which lists `<section>`.

So therefore, your HTML is valid: `<section>` can be a descendant of `<footer>`, however `<header>`, `<footer>`, and `<main>` cannot.